# Cordova angular offline check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have below code to check online/offline in my cordova application.

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell2G';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell3G';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell4G';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cellgeneric';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'Nonetwork';
alert(states[networkState]);
if(states[networkState]!='Nonetwork'){
online=true;
}else{
online=false;
}
```

And my angular controller is like below.

```
 .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$http','$localStorage','$state',function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $state){ 


  if(online==true){

    //code for online
  }else{
    // code for offline
   } 


}])
```

I called the checking in 'deviceready' event,the status getting .but my problem is - `deviceready` is called after my controller is started.is it possible to check the network status before angular controller started execution?

Comment: In your exemple, I cannot see where `deviceready` is called. May be there is some elements missing. Where do you call the first block of code checking network ?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, controller are executed during **the running phase** of your application. You can execute some code before that running phase, also called **configuration phase**.

You shoudl read [module documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) from angular.

> - Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants
>     can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent
>     accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully
>     configured.
> - Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>     injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>     configuration during application run time.

In your code, it should looks like this :

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
  // This is an example of config block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
  // into config blocks.
}).
run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
  // This is an example of a run block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
  // into run blocks
});
```

Not sure if I understood well, but that might let you execute code before running your controller :)

*Just on thought about your code ... config will be run only once and your connection can change over time (if in a car, going from 4G to 3G). So might need to check regularely or check in your controller. Best case could be a function you call at the activation of your contoller.*